# Visual Studio 2019: code was closed after debugging and i couldn't debugging again

Tags: debugging, ide, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019: code was closed after debugging and i couldn't debugging again.
If I want to debug again, I can only restart the solution.

Comment: Hi friend, what's your project type? And can you share more details about the experience you encountered, I'm not sure about what `the code was closed` mean, do you mean the text editor is closed or the whole solution is closed? If the text editor is closed, can you reopen the file in [Solution Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#solution-explorer)?

Answer (score 0):

1.Try `Tools=>Import and Export settings=>Reset all settings=>No, just reset...` to check if it makes some help. If some setting in VS caused that issue, reset can help.

2.And if the code you mean is source files, you can open the Solution Explorer and reopen it easily there:

[image]

3.If you do meet a strange situation in which the code is closed and can't be opened until you reopen the solution, I guess you may need to [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).